# When we get column name plus integer in select query in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SP(Stored Procedure) and it have 6 temptable which contain deleted/inserted values from different 6 tables using `OUTPUT` clause. Some columns are similar in all the 6 temptable.

Now when i am using

```
select * 
from #temp1 
left join other tables
```

.

I am getting correct data but the weird thing is the column name.
Somthing like this is happening

```
symbol | symbol1 | Symbol2 |... etc
```

I am getting column names but with added integer with them.

I am unable to understand why is it happening.

Help.

Comment: Same column names in tables?

Comment: This is how duplicate column names are handled.

Comment: Post the full query you used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Got what is happening, sp is returning correct output. Problem is with my DataSet (I am using `C#`) and this `DataSet` is converting my column in symbol1,symbol2 .. etc.